# How to save exported excel at server directory

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, excel-interop

I want to export data table in Excel sheet and saving in server directory in MVC application. Here is my code-

//ManagEmployeeController.cs

```
public JsonResult ExportToExcel()
        {
            Excel.ExcelUtlity obj = new Excel.ExcelUtlity();
            DataTable dt = ConvertToDataTable(ListEmployee());
            string dir = string.Format("~/Clients/ExportedData/");
            var directoryToSaveFile = Server.MapPath(dir);
            string uniqueNumber = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            string file = "ContactExportData.xlsx";
            string newFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", uniqueNumber, file);
            if (!Directory.Exists(directoryToSaveFile))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryToSaveFile);
            }
            string fullFilePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}",dir,newFileName); ;
            //obj.WriteDataTableToExcel(dt, "Person Details", "D:\\testPersonExceldata.xlsx", "Details");
            obj.WriteDataTableToExcel(dt, "Person Details", fullFilePath, "Details");
            var result = new { Success = "Success", Messaage = "SuccessMessage" };
            return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The directory gets created but file does not saved here. But if I use commented code(`obj.WriteDataTableToExcel(dt, "Person Details", "D:\\testPersonExceldata.xlsx", "Details");`) the file gets saved on my local directory D.

//ExcelUtility.cs

```
 public bool WriteDataTableToExcel(System.Data.DataTable dataTable, string worksheetName, string saveAsLocation, string ReporType)
        {
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelworkBook;
    //
    //
    excelworkBook.SaveAs(saveAsLocation);;
       }

What is missing in my code in order to save Excel to mentioned directory on server?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string fullFilePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}",dir,newFileName);`

should be:

`string fullFilePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}",directoryToSaveFile,newFileName);`

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. Not able to vote your answer due to less reputation(15)